# How to include other source files using the #use directive in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm a newbie with OCaml and I'd like to put some of the code into another file, say `foo.ml`, just as one would do in C++ or Python. But that part of code itself does not form a module.

I've included `#use "foo.ml"` in the head of my main source file. But when I build my project using `ocamlbuild`, it reports `I/O error: "foo.ml: No such file or directory"`. But clearly `foo.ml` is in the current working directory.

I wonder if anyone knows how to achieve that aim in OCaml and let my project be built, or if that is not a convention in OCaml? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`#use "foo.ml"` is a directive for the interactive toplevel, it doesn't work with the compiler.

If you want to split your code in different files (which is a good idea and is strongly recommended in OCaml), then you should use the module system.
Why do you say your code doesn't form a module? If your code consists only of single-use functions, they should be in the same file as the functions that use them. If your code is reusable, then it forms a module.

Comment: Thanks and I shall adopt your practice.

Answer (score 4):

As Thomash already said, it's probably the wrong solution for your problem.

If you need it anyway, you must use camlp4 or external tools like [cppo](http://mjambon.com/cppo.html).

example for pa_macro (shipped with ocaml):

test2.ml:

```
let arg = "Hello World"
```

test.ml:

```
INCLUDE "test2.ml"
let () =
   print_endline arg
```

compilation:

```
 ocamlfind ocamlc -syntax camlp4o -package camlp4 -ppopt pa_macro.cmo test.ml -o test
```

Comment: Thank you. Quite interested in camlp4.